# TestNG is not updating database using Spring Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, testng

I am using TestNG in my application having framework GWT,Spring and Hibernate.
In my TestNG class i am trying to create the DaoImpl class object which is used to perform add/update/delete operation in database using hibernate(i am using hibenratetemplate here for transaction) and my code is working fine for add/update/delete operation while running the application.

But when i am running my testng class, i am able to get the bean object of DaoImpl and able to read the data from database but while trying to perform update/delete operation in database, testng method executed successfully database remains unaffected means no change in DB.

So want to know is it possible to test update/delete database method using TestNG or not and if yes what is the way to do that.

My code of TestNg class is given below

```
Public class RoleMgmtDAOImplTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
RoleMgmtDAOImpl roleMgmtDAOImpl;
     @BeforeClass
        public void setup() {
          Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
          roleMgmtDAOImpl=(RoleMgmtDAOImpl) applicationContext.getBean("roleDAO");
          Assert.assertNotNull(roleMgmtDAOImpl);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up transactions properly, take a look at this link:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx

So you probably need the following annotations on your class:

@ContextConfiguration(...)      // context should include transaction manager
@TransactionConfiguration(...)  // name of transaction manager if non-default
@Transactional

By default I believe a transaction will then be created for each test and rolled back at the end of each test (so you won't see any changes to the db after the tests have run).

Typically you don't want your test data persisted.  If you do, you can change the default rollback behaviour within the @TransactionConfiguration annotation at class level or with the @Rollback annotation at test level, see:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations

In terms of testing updates/deletes, I don't suggest you change the default rollback behaviour.  Instead you could find the object (within the same test and therefore transaction) after the update and assert your changes.

Comment: This is the right way to test with the Spring framework. If you want to test that some database operation happened, though, you should flush() and clear() the session in between, or you'll be hitting the [first level cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-sessioncache).

Answer (score 1):

The point is, as suggested Corin, the @Rollback annotation. If it is not used, database changes are not really performed into your database.